# Why $\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}\notin \{a+b\sqrt{d}\in\mathbb{C}:a,b \in\mathbb{Z}\} $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $d\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ be an Square-free integer ${\displaystyle d\equiv 1{\pmod {4}}}$. Why $\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}\notin \{a+b\sqrt{d}\in\mathbb{C}:a,b \in\mathbb{Z}\} $ ?

Comment: Which integers $a,b$ do you propose it to be?

Comment: Show $1$ and $\sqrt6$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.  Can you finish from there?

Comment: It’s not true if $d=1.$ But it is true more generally if $d$ is not a perfect square - you don’t need $d\equiv 1\pmod 4.$

Comment: Comment on the question behind your question. That complex number is an algebraic integer since the congruence condition on $d$ implies that it satisfies a monic quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2} = a + b \sqrt{d}$ then
$$\sqrt{d} = \frac{2a-1}{1-2b}
$$
If $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ this proves $\sqrt{d}$ is rational (using that $b \ne \frac{1}{2}$). But if $d$ is square free then $\sqrt{d}$ is not rational.

Comment: Why $d$  is square free then $\sqrt{d}$ is not rational ?

Comment: If $b$ is an integer, it is not equal to $\frac12$.

Comment: Perhaps you've seen the ancient Greek proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational. There is a modern proof using uniqueness of prime factorization, which extends to all $\sqrt{d}$ such that $d$ is square free. But that's another question.

Comment: Good point @Tomasz, edited my answer.

Comment: Technically, $d=1$ is square-free and $1\pmod 4.$ But this is true if $d\neq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, show:

> **Lemma:** If $d\in\mathbb Z$ is not a perfect square, and $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in \mathbb Q$ and $$a_1+b_1\sqrt d =a_2+b_2\sqrt d$$ then $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2.$

**Hint:** Use that $\sqrt d$ is not rational. It is either an irrational real number if $d>0$ or imaginary if $d<0.$

---

In particular, if $a_1=b_1=\frac12,$ then there are no integers $a_2,b_2,$ since $\frac 12\notin \mathbb Z.$

So, you don’t need $d\equiv 1\pmod 4,$ nor do you need $d$ square-free (it works for $d=12,$ or $d=-4,$) but you do need to exclude $d=1.$

Indeed, if $d=1$ then:

$$\frac12+\frac12\sqrt 1=1+0\sqrt 1.$$